# ListView Rowlayout in a own coded Chat

Tags: android, android-layout, chat

### **What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to create a chat which has to diffrent row's. For every row I made a own layout file, but the problem is that the layoutfile of one row dosn't fit the screen.

### **Question**

What do I need to change in the row layout that it fits like it should. You'll find the code and also a printscreen of what I'm trying.

[image]

**Code**

---

ListAdapter
    public class ChatListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
            private ArrayList<String> ContentList;
            private ArrayList<Integer> ChatUserList;

            private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

            public ChatListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> _ContentList,
                                   ArrayList<Integer> _ChatUserList) {
                        ContentList = _ContentList;
                        ChatUserList = _ChatUserList;
                        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                                               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            }

            public int getCount() {
                        return ContentList.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                        return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                        return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        View vi = convertView;
                        TextView tv_text;
                        TextView tv_date;

                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

                        if (ChatUserList.get(position) == 1) {
                                   // I'm RECIVER -> Message is left align
                                   vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout_leftalign, null);
                                   tv_text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_chat_leftalign);
                                   tv_date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_chat_leftalign_date);
                        } else {
                                   // I'm SENDER -> Message is right align
                                   vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout_rightalign, null);
                                   tv_text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_chat_rightalign);
                                   tv_date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_chat_rightalign_date);
                        }

                        tv_date.setText(sdf.format(new Date()));
                        tv_text.setText(ContentList.get(position));
                        tv_text.setMaxWidth(((Chat.display.getWidth() / 4) * 3));

                        return vi;
            }
```

RowLayout XML Left (Blue bubbles)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly_rf_row_r"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_rightalign"
        android:paddingBottom="2.5dp"
        android:paddingTop="2.5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_chat_rightalign"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_chat_rightalign_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv_chat_rightalign"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="8.5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

RowLayout XML right (red bubbles)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly_rf_row_l"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_leftalign"
        android:paddingBottom="2.5dp"
        android:paddingTop="2.5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_chat_leftalign"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_chat_leftalign_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_chat_leftalign"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="8.5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for both XML add  `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` like followings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
```

and so on...

Comment: its not clear whats represents the red chat & blue chat. I provide this ans by taking a over view of your code.

Comment: take a look at the printscreen there you see a blue and a red message bubble ;) thats what I mean

Comment: i am sure you have problem in the both layouts, actually form a distance its not possible to detect the exact error without checking it in practically. So my suggestion is check the both layout, mainly the layout_width/height part, alignParentRight/Left parts thoroughly in all items. Hopefully you will solve your problem. all the best.

Comment: i recoded the whole code.. whatever now it works.. but the green tick is for you