# Unable to set left and right conversation while using custom listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, xmpp, chat, smack

Am developing a chat application.I have done them using smack library.Everything works fine,even the users also can chat with each other but am unable set the incoming messages to the right side of the `ListView` . I have tried to the gravity of the `TextView` to Right.But am unable to achieve it.I referred some these questions but i didn't helped me!

1.[Left and Right alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762473/left-and-right-alignment-rows-inside-listview)

2.[Listview Row Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226884/listview-rowlayout-in-a-own-coded-chat)

```
public class ChatRoom extends Activity {
    private final static String SERVER_HOST = "talk.google.com";
    private final static int SERVER_PORT = 5222;
    private final static String SERVICE_NAME = "gmail.com";
    private final static String LOGIN = "acd@gmail.com";
    private final static String PASSWORD = "password";
    private List<String> m_discussionThread;
    private XMPPConnection m_connection;
    private Handler m_handler;
    private String mtemp_user_id;
    private ProgressDialog p_dialog;
    EditText mMsg;
    ListView listview;
    MyAdapter myadpter;
    String fromName;
    String mtempSpecial;
    String SendMSg, RecievdMsg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_screen);
        PrepareChat prechat = new PrepareChat(); //AsyncTask
        m_handler = new Handler();
        p_dialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatRoom.this);
        m_discussionThread = new ArrayList<String>();
        myadpter = new MyAdapter(m_discussionThread);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        mtemp_user_id = bundle.getString("USER");

        prechat.execute();


        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_);
        listview.setAdapter(myadpter);

        mMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_msg);
        findViewById(R.id.b_MSG_To).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                SendMSg = "SEND";
                Message msg = new Message(mtemp_user_id, Message.Type.chat);
                msg.setBody(mMsg.getText().toString());
                m_connection.sendPacket(msg);
                m_discussionThread.add(mMsg.getText().toString());
                mMsg.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    public class PrepareChat extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            p_dialog.setMessage("Preparing chat");
            p_dialog.setCancelable(false);
            p_dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            System.out.println("In do in back ...");
            try {
                initConnection();
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            p_dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private void initConnection() throws XMPPException {
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT, SERVICE_NAME);
        m_connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
        m_connection.connect();

        m_connection.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("After LOGInd");
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        presence.setStatus("available");
        m_connection.sendPacket(presence);
        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        m_connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;

                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                            .getFrom());

                    String mtempSpecial = message.getBody().toString();
                    m_discussionThread.add(mtemp_user_id + mtempSpecial);
                    RecievdMsg = "RE";
                    m_handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            myadpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            listview.setSelection(myadpter.getCount() - 1);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, filter);
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        LayoutInflater layoutinflate;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Context context;

        public MyAdapter(List<String> m_discussionThread) {
            list = m_discussionThread;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int items) {
            return items;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int posi) {
            return posi;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup view_Group) {
            View view_ = arg1;
            LayoutInflater layout_inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (SendMSg.equals("SEND")) {
                view_ = layout_inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_b, view_Group,
                        false);
                TextView tv_MyMsg = (TextView) view_
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_mymsg);
                System.out.println("in send loop");
            //  tv_MyMsg.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                tv_MyMsg.setText(list.get(position)); //TextView not binding to the right.
                SendMSg = "";
            } else {
                view_ = layout_inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_ab, view_Group,
                        false);
                TextView tv_FromMsg = (TextView) view_
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_From_Msg);
                tv_FromMsg.setText(list.get(position)); 
                /*
                 * tv_ToMsg.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                 * System.out.println("in else"); tv_FromMsg.setText("");
                 * tv_ToMsg.setText(list.get(position));
                 */}


            return view_;
        }

    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Only chat_ab.xml getting populated but chat_b.xml which contains green text is ignored.

`chat_ab.xml` ...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_From_Msg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FF00FF" />
```

`chat_b.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_mymsg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

What i got so far is this[image: Up screen shot]
What am expecting is My Message(out going) to the right of the `ListView` And outgoing to the left of the screen.
Please Do suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with using `android:gravity` and `android:layout_gravity` attributes in LinearLayout.

Please Refer [Android Listview for chat application.](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html)

Comment: am Adding incoming and out going messages to the different layouts which are already aligned left and right have a look at chat_b.xml and chat_ab.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use different layouts for textview inside list view. Every time the list view populates with a new entry (message), compare the current users Auth by the sender's Auth by using user.getEmail().
If they match, set layout gravity of aforementioned textview to right, else left.